# Haskell System is a member of unusable hidden package

Tags: haskell

`System` is absolutely brimming with handy useful IO stuff, but apparently it's been deprecated I am to understand (presuming this because it was moved into the deprecated haskell98 package), that said; is there any info out there about where it's components have been dispersed to?

I want to use `System.timeout`, but since I can't use `System`, I am guessing `timeout` has been moved to a different module. Which module was it moved to? What modules were any of the other `System` bits moved to?

Answer (score 6):

The old `System` module has been split into several hierarchical modules under the `System` namespace. For example, `timeout` is now in the [`System.Timeout`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Timeout.html) module.

You can see all of the `System.*` modules--and more besides--on the documentation for [base](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/index.html).

For specific functions, you can also always search on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Comment: I am so stupid, I kept looking at the [hackage page for System.Timeout](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.0/doc/html/System-Timeout.html) and reading it as System.timeout thinking it was documentation for just the function inside the System module (which made sense because it's the only thing in the whole module)

Comment: `System` was a module, not package ;)